# R: Assigning period identifiers to individual events

Tags: r, datetime, period

I came across the following problem: I would like to assign a period identifier to individual events which fall between the start and end date of the period in question. As the periods occur in different locations, I need to assign the period identifier separated for each location. How could I do this?

Example:

```
id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2) #country
id2 = c(1:3)        # electoral period by country
dateP2 = c(10, 20, 30, 5, 15, 25) # end period
dateP1 = c(NA, 10, 20, NA, 5, 15) # begin period
dfperiod = data.frame(id, id2, dateP1, dateP2)  

id = c(1,2,2,1,2)  #country
eventid =c(1:5)   
dateE =c(5,15,17,12,4) # event date
dfevent = data.frame(id, dateE, eventid)
```

Comment: Is there any reason the first period starts at `NA` instead of `0`? This problem is easier if the event date is between the start and end date.

Comment: Yes, the data set in question only contains the end date of the period. The start date is generated by lagging the end date, which should produce an NA for every first observation per country.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A relatively simple solution is to join the two dataframes and filter accordingly. This may not be an optimal solution if the dataframes are particularly large.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2) #country
id2 = c(1:3)        # electoral period by country
dateP2 = c(10, 20, 30, 5, 15, 25) # end period
dateP1 = c(NA, 10, 20, NA, 5, 15) # begin period
dfperiod = data.frame(id, id2, dateP1, dateP2)  

dfperiod
#>   id id2 dateP1 dateP2
#> 1  1   1     NA     10
#> 2  1   2     10     20
#> 3  1   3     20     30
#> 4  2   1     NA      5
#> 5  2   2      5     15
#> 6  2   3     15     25

id = c(1,2,2,1,2)  #country
eventid =c(1:5)   
dateE =c(5,15,17,12,4) # event date
dfevent = data.frame(id, dateE, eventid)

dfevent
#>   id dateE eventid
#> 1  1     5       1
#> 2  2    15       2
#> 3  2    17       3
#> 4  1    12       4
#> 5  2     4       5

dfevent %>% 
  left_join(dfperiod, by = c("id" = "id")) %>% 
  filter(dateE > ifelse(is.na(dateP1),0,dateP1),  dateE <= dateP2)
#>   id dateE eventid id2 dateP1 dateP2
#> 1  1     5       1   1     NA     10
#> 2  2    15       2   2      5     15
#> 3  2    17       3   3     15     25
#> 4  1    12       4   2     10     20
#> 5  2     4       5   1     NA      5
```

Comment: Dear Eumenedies thank you very much for your response! Can you elaborate on what you mean by particularly large? The event data set in question contains roughly 170000 events.

Comment: @SimonP. It would on both data sets, i.e. the size of `dfperiod` as well. it would also depend on the machine you are using. It's difficult to say but I would be happy to do the above on my aging laptop with 1700000 rows. All I could recommend is that you give it a go. If it takes longer than you want, you can always kill it (just make sure you save your environment or something first.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer. I did give it a go with the data in question and it produced the following error:  
Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : 
  Evaluation error: dims [product 69288] do not match the length of object [1054640].
In addition: Warning message:
In (~date > ifelse(is.na(lagelec), 0, lagelec)) & (~STARTdf <= legelecdate) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length                  Do you have any recommendations what to do now?

Comment: @SimonP. I think what is going on here is that you are calling a variable within your `filter` call. Here the first `"id"` is the name of the id column in the first dataframe and the second is the second (`dfperiod`). In the filter, `dateE` is the name of the column in the `dfevent` dataframe. Also make sure you are using the right column names for `dateP1` and `dateP2`. If that's not the problem, please provide the actual, exact words you type and tell me which column is which in the example.

Comment: Thank you so much. After correcting my stupid mistake ( i called a dataframe instead of a variable)  it works perfectly fine. Thanks for your time and effort!